# Braintree: Submit button color change

Tags: android, android-studio, braintree

There is a submit button with a default bluish color appearing. I want to change it to purple color. Any idea how it can be done for Braintree Android ?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The submit button is one of the few things that doesn't respond to theme customizations. This may be resolved soon, but in the short term you would need to develop a custom integration using your own form and handle card tokenization yourself. The best guide for this is the [Braintree Credit Card Guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/overview).

Comment: Can we add a back button for back navigation on this screen ?

Comment: is the support for theme customization for the submit still unavailable, And is it possible to change the text from **ADD CARD** to **PAY**